# Reusable container component with state and dynamic child component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to have a reusable component that can instantiate a dynamic component:

```
function EditableElement({endpoint, data, ElementFormClass}) {
    const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(data);
    const [deleted, setDeleted] = useState(false);

    if (deleted) return (<p>X_X</p>);

    if (edit) return ElementFormClass(
        endpoint,
        data,
        setFormData,
        pk => {
            setDeleted(true);
        },
        e => setEdit(false)
    )

    return (
        <p onClick={e => setEdit(true)}>{formData.name}</p>
    )
}

function ElementFormDisplayOne({endpoint, data, cancel, updateData, deleteData}) {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(data);
    // const [deleted, setDeleted] = useState(false);
    // if (deleted) return (<p style={{color: 'red'}}>DELETED</p>);
    return (
        <form onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            updateData(formData);
            cancel();
        }}>
            <label htmlFor={formData.pk}>{formData.name}</label>
            <input type="text" id={formData.pk} value={formData.name}
                   onChange={e => setFormData({...formData, name: e.target.value})}/>
            <button type="button" onClick={cancel}>cancel</button>
            <button type="submit">ok</button>
            <button type="button" onClick={e => deleteData(formData.pk)}>delete</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

It's used like this:

```
<div>
    <h3>Gallery Form ONE</h3>
    {data.map(el => <EditableElement endpoint={'update'} key={el.pk} data={el}
                                     ElementFormClass={ElementFormDisplayOne}/>)}
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Gallery Form TWO</h3>
    {data2.map(el => <EditableElement endpoint={'update'} key={el.pk} data={el}
                                      ElementFormClass={ElementFormDisplayTwo}/>)}
</div>
```

But it throws

> Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

Is what I want possible in ReactJs?
Note: I'm not using Redux and don't intend to

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reusable-container-component-with-state-and-dynamic-child-component-d8m7d?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You'll get this error when a hook is conditionally executed or when it is executed inside of a loop. I don't see either case in the code you pasted so far. Can you paste more of the code in the bottom code block where it's rendering `<h3>Gallery Form ONE</h3>`?

Comment: @RossAllen I edited the question to include a codebox example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your error in line 104 of your codesandbox by converting your function into an actual JSX element.

```
if (edit)
    return (<ElementFormClass
      endpoint={endpoint}
      data={data}
      setFormData={setFormData}
      cb1 = {(pk) => setDeleted(true)}
      cb2 = {(e) => setEdit(false)}
    />);
```

This is a common error people face in react, where they use a react component as a function rather than JSX.

Comment: Your solution fixed the error but I don't understand why. Do you have any resource to read about it? Also, the cancel/update/delete don't work, not sure if it's logic error.

Comment: yeah your update delete stuff won't work cus I gave some generic names to your callbacks(cb1 and cb2).

Comment: I looked more carefully over the code and now i understand what my mistake was. Thanks!